# Add a custom row in R, when a specific row does not exist

Tags: r

I have a dataset like this:

```
dat <- read.table(text = "
X1    X2     var1  var2  var3 arrowhead
Z1    A3        0     0   252 normal   
Z1    Z1        0   268     0 none     
Z2    A1        0     0   262 normal   
Z2    Z2        0   108     0 none     
Z3    A2        0     0   253 normal   
Z3    D         0     0     0 odot     
Z3    Z3        0    95     0 none     
Z5    IN        0     0    54 normal   
Z5    Z2        0     0   148 normal   
Z5    Z5        0   255     0 none  
", header = TRUE)

  X1    X2     var1  var2  var3 arrowhead
   <chr> <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>    
 Z1    A3        0     0   252 normal   
 Z1    Z1        0   268     0 none     
 Z2    A1        0     0   262 normal   
 Z2    Z2        0   108     0 none     
 Z3    A2        0     0   253 normal   
 Z3    D         0     0     0 odot     
 Z3    Z3        0    95     0 none     
 Z5    IN        0     0    54 normal   
 Z5    Z2        0     0   148 normal   
 Z5    Z5        0   255     0 none
```

What I need to do is look for a specific pairing of X1 and X2 in rows - ex. Z1 and Z2, OR Z2 and Z1 (the order doesn't matter).  When this doesn't exist (like in the df above) I would like to add a custom row so I can add a new row containing X1 = Z1, X2 = Z2, var1 = 0, etc.

I've been trying a combination of
"ifelse(is.null(dat$X1 =='Z1'& dat$X2 == 'Z2' | dat$X1 =='Z2'& dat$X2 == 'Z1'),
add_row "

but am pretty stuck.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You mean like a row underneath a matching row? Why not made a custom column or two with the True/False values so that you can subset on them?  For example: `dat$X1Z1 <- dat$X1 =='Z1'` will give you T/F values. Then you can use logical operators to subset, including ones like `any()` and `all()`. R tends to work best if you think column-wise for data frames.

Comment: Thanks David! This is a logical approach. I'll try it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this

```
if(!any(apply(dat[, c("X1", "X2")], 1, function(x) 
    (x["X1"]=="Z1" & x["X2"]=="Z2") | (x["X1"]=="Z2" & x["X2"]=="Z1")))){
  rbind(dat, c("Z1", "Z2", 0, 0, 253, "normal"))
} else {
  dat
}
   X1 X2 var1 var2 var3 arrowhead
1  Z1 A3    0    0  252    normal
2  Z1 Z1    0  268    0      none
3  Z2 A1    0    0  262    normal
4  Z2 Z2    0  108    0      none
5  Z3 A2    0    0  253    normal
6  Z3  D    0    0    0      odot
7  Z3 Z3    0   95    0      none
8  Z5 IN    0    0   54    normal
9  Z5 Z2    0    0  148    normal
10 Z5 Z5    0  255    0      none
11 Z1 Z2    0    0  253    normal
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but I'm getting stuck at: unexpected token '\'. I apologize if there is something silly I'm missing.

Comment: @ChristopherCourse `\()` is short for `function(x)`, introduced around R version 4.1. I'll change the definition to the old one, should work then.

Comment: Ah, thanks. and yep works!